# Getting 404 from C# call but 200 from Postman

Tags: c#, webclient, restsharp

I'm trying call API from C# code but I'm getting 404 all the time. I'm sending the same request from Postman and always result is 200.

My requests:
[image: postman request]

```
        var body = new RequestBody
        {
            AdultCount = 1,
            ChildCount = 0,
            FlightList = new List<RequestFlightBody>
            {
                new RequestFlightBody
                {
                    ArrivalStation = fromCode,
                    DepartureStation = toCode,
                    FromDateTime = tomorrow,
                    ToDateTime = lastDate
                },
                new RequestFlightBody
                {
                    ArrivalStation = toCode,
                    DepartureStation = fromCode,
                    FromDateTime = tomorrow,
                    ToDateTime = lastDate
                }
            },
            InfantCount = 0,
            PriceType = "regular"
        };

        var client = new RestClient("https://be.wizzair.com/9.4.3");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.Resource = "api/search/timetable";
        request.AddJsonBody(body);
        var result = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

        if (result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlightBody>(result.Content);
            await SaveResults(model);
        }
```

From this code result is always NoContent. I tried to use code  generated by postman and result is NoContent too. When I copy serialized object to postman as body - is 200 from postman.

Any ideas what is wrong??

EDIT:
I looked for headers od fiddler and they are different:
postman:
[image: postman request]
code: 
[image: code request]

for code:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"https://be.wizzair.com");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.Resource = @"9.4.3/api/search/timetable";
        request.AddHeader("host", "be.wizzair.com:443");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", @"*/*");
        request.AddHeader("User-Agent", @"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", @"close");
        request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

Should/Can I simulate request with the same headers? I don't know why added headers are missed.

Comment: 404 means: not found, is api/search/timetable the correct path, or is there a Capital or forward slash missing in the c# code (/api/search/timetable OR Api/search/timetable  )? (note, PostMan offers a code button (under the send button, that can generate c# code)

Comment: I see Headers(1) in PostMan, what is that ?

Comment: And maybe Api != api, depending on the service.

Comment: few suggestions: 1) move "9.4.3" to `Resource` assignment. 2) do the same case for `Resource` as in Postman, e.g. "Api". 3) Ensure that serialization fields name have the same case (do you use `JsonProperty` attribute to set low case JSON name? i.e. ArrivalStation should be serialized as arrivalStation.). Can you provide definition of `RequestFlightBody` class?

Comment: @Max - a problem in capitalization in the body ought to return 400 Bad Request, but agin, the implementation could get that wrong.

Comment: After further investigiations I think it is a slash before api since the api is not case sensitive (tested it in postman)  try var client = new RestClient("https://be.wizzair.com/9.4.3/");

Comment: 4) date field serialization. How do you set specific date-to-JSON-string format? By default, on my computer `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now)` returns ""\"2019-01-29T10:23:08.1649872+13:00\""" which is not exactly as expected.

Comment: Looks like you are missing headers in C# which you have in postman.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ;) I tried both /api and /Api, move 9.4.3 to resource and tried '@' (I tried it again to be sure). Everything is serialized with low case - with JsonProperty attribute and when i copy serialized body do postman it's works. I copied code from working postman request and execute in C# code but it is still NoContent ;)

Comment: Postman use only Content-Type header i tried add this in C# code too but still 404.

Comment: So, as @Alexander mentioned, you, probably, missing `Host` header, which of Postman adds automatically. Also, what is about authentication?

Comment: I tried add host and other headers. Look at edited post

Comment: Are you able to show us the Fiddler requests and responses (including payloads) - both for working and non-working? _At first glance it looks like a capitalization problem._

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is probably because Wizzair is rejecting requests from unknown/black listed UserAgents to prevent "unauthorized" use of their API. Try userAgent from postman or browser - set it with

`client.UserAgent = @"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0";`

as regular User-Agent header will be overriten (I assume you are using RestSharp).
I've checked it myself - out of curiosity, since your example should work - and it seems to  work with changed User-Agent

Comment: You're right! But problem is with .net core. I created two console apps: in .net 4.6.1 and in net core 2.1 with the same code. From 4.6.1 User-Agent is correct but from net core is not setting (sniffed by Fiddler). Any idea how to set User-Agent on .net core?